# Using array pointer yields an error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
      int N, i,j,k;
      int uglyNumber[1500]={1};
      int *i=uglyNumber;
      int *j=uglyNumber;
      int *k=uglyNumber;

      while(scanf("%d",&N)!=EOF)
      printf("%d\n",uglyNumber[N]);
  }
```

produces compiler error：

```
int differs in levels of indirection from int *
```

Why I can not use the pointer to refer the array `uglyNumber[]`?

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? On which line? And is that *all* you get? There isn't any more text? If there is, please edit the question to include the *all* error/warning messages.

Comment: You are also redifining i,j,k. And your code readhes an and of function without return.

Comment: Oh, if you give something that is not an integer for `scanf` it will return zero. Also, what will happen if the user enters a negative number?

Comment: i,j,k is int. I made a fool mistake!

Comment: Just a heads-up: `i`, `j` and `k` are declared twice, as different types. And what you have is an array (`uglyNumber`), and pointers to ints (`*i`, `*j` and `*k`). Pointers are not ints, but arrays can decay into pointers

Comment: please check an answer as right to close the question

Answer (score 5):

I think you get your error because you define `i`,`j`,`k` twice. the other parts of the code should run.

Answer (score 2):

Won't compile.
You've already declared `i,j,k` as int.

So you can not declare `*i,*j,*k`.

After changing `*i,*j,*k` to `*ii,*jj,*kk`.It compiled and is OK to run.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers i, j & k should only point to one element of array i.e. uglyNumber[0], uglyNumber[1] & so on ..

Also pointer is a variable that stores the address of the element of array. To store, you must use & sign i.e. *i= &uglyNumber[0]

Comment: The assignment `i = &uglyNumber[0]` is equivalent in every way to the assignment `i = uglyNumber`.

Answer (score -1):

Please check that you have initialized the value of N. It may be a garbage one.

Comment: `scanf()` will **put** the new value in the variable. Don't worry about the existing value.